# Using variables in a sed command

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to add some text (a path) at the end of a line which is found by a sed command:

```
var="/folder1/folder2/folder3"

sed -i "/Begins with this text/s/$/$var/" filename
```

I know that double quotes are needed to use variables in a sed command but if I use the above command it gives me an error message saying:

```
expresssion #1, character 23: unknown option to `s
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It works for me. Is there a `/` in the actual value of `$var`?

Comment: Yes I am actually saving a path in the variable like `/folder/folder2/folder3`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Change the delimiter in the substitute command to something that won't appear in `$var`, e.g.

```
sed -i "/Begins with this text/s|$|$var|" filename
```

or escape the slashes in `$var`:

```
var="\/folder1\/folder2\/folder3"
```